# Delete duplicate id and Value ROW using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, duplicates

In SQL Server 2008 R2 I added two duplicate ID and record in my table. When I try to delete one of the last two records I receive the following error.

> *The row values updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows.*

The data is:

```
7   ABC         6
7   ABC         6
7   ABC         6
8   XYZ         1
8   XYZ         1
8   XYZ         4
7   ABC         6
7   ABC         6
```

I need to delete last two records:

```
7   ABC         6
7   ABC         6
```

I have been trying to delete last 2 record using the feature "Edit the Top 200 rows" to delete this duplicate id but get the error above.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an outline of code I use to delete dups in tables that may have many dups.

```
/* I always put the rollback and commit up here in comments until I am sure I have 
   done what I wanted. */
BEGIN tran Jim1 -- rollback tran Jim1 -- Commit tran Jim1; DROP table PnLTest.dbo.What_Jim_Deleted

/* This creates a table to put the deleted rows in just in case I'm really screwed up */
SELECT top 1 *, NULL dupflag 
  INTO jt1.dbo.What_Jim_Deleted --DROP TABLE jt1.dbo.What_Jim_Deleted
  FROM jt1.dbo.tab1;
/* This removes the row without removing the table */
TRUNCATE TABLE jt1.dbo.What_Jim_Deleted;

/* the cte assigns a row number to each unique security for each day, dups will have a
   rownumber > 1.  The fields in the partition by are from the composite key for the 
   table (if one exists.  These are the queries that I ran to show them as dups

SELECT compkey1, compkey2, compkey3, compkey4, COUNT(*) 
  FROM jt1.dbo.tab1
  GROUP BY compkey1, compkey2, compkey3, compkey4
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ORDER BY 1 DESC


*/
with getthedups as
  (SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (partition by compkey1,compkey2, compkey3, compkey4 
                          ORDER BY Timestamp desc) dupflag /*This can be anything that gives some order to the rows (even if order doesn't matter) */
     FROM jt1.dbo.tab1)
/* This delete is deleting from the cte which cascades to the underlying table 
   The Where is part of the Delete (even though it comes after the OUTPUT.  The
   OUTPUT takes all of the DELETED row and inserts them into the "oh shit" table,
   just in case.*/
DELETE 
  FROM getthedups 
  OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO jti.dbo.What_Jim_Deleted
  WHERE dupflag > 1

--Check the resulting tables here to ensure that you did what you think you did

/* If all has gone well then commit the tran and drop the "oh shit" table, or let it 
   hang around for a while. */
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have given no clue whatsoever that there are other columns in the table, assuming your data is in 3 columns A,B,C, you can delete 2 rows using:

```
;with t as (
    select top(2) *
      from tbl
     where A = 7 and B = 'ABC' and C = 6
)
DELETE t;
```

This will arbitrarily match two rows based on the conditions, and delete them.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would adding a `UNIQUE` index also remove the duplicates?

Comment: @njk Not in Sql Server... the duplicate values would actually prevent the unique index from being created successfully.

Comment: I might be thinking of creating a new temp table with a unique index.

Comment: Can't it be just `DELETE TOP(2) FROM tbl WHERE ...` ?

Comment: @njk - He **already** has 3 copies. 2 more were added that need to be removed.

Comment: @njk You might also be thinking of MySql, where the [unique index will actually delete duplicates](http://www.mikeperham.com/2012/03/02/deleting-duplicate-rows-in-mysql/) like you say...

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi Thanks for you help but when I executed that query it removed entire (7   ABC   6) from table and only                 8   XYZ         1
8   XYZ         1
8   XYZ         4  values are left.